# print the firefox session id and command executor url: What does it mean?

Tags: firefox, sessionid

> A person sent the below text as a requirement for a task to be
> performed in python script. But I really don't know what he wants.

**His Message:**
*"Print the firefox session id and command executor url; open "https://iwastesomuchtime.com/" in an already opened FireFox browser; click "random". This is all."*